# Datetime issue in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime, postgresql

I am trying to add the datetime object of a person. Whenever the birth year is less than year 1942, I get a strange error `DataError: unable to parse time` when reading the data back from the DB.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    """A simple class to hold the person info
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    born = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Whenever I try to add the born `datetime` object of a person born in the year 1929 and then try to read it, It fails.

Let me re-iterate that the data insertion works fine, but fails during the read. I am assuming that something wrong in going on inside the DB.

I did a set of tests and got to know that it fails whenever I add the person born in or before year 1940. It gives `DataError: unable to parse time`

I am using PostgreSQL.

Any sort of help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't duplicate this at all (postgresql 8.3, psycopg2 2.0.3, django 1.0 final, python 2.5). What version of postgres are you using, and what version of the driver?

Comment: Version is psql (PostgreSQL) 8.3.7,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only thing I could come up with here can be found in the [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/6.3/static/c0804.htm). My guess is that Django is storing your date in a "reltime" field, which can only go back 68 years. My calculator verifies that 2009-68 == 1941, which seems very close to what you reported.

I would recommend looking over the schema of your table, by running the following command:

```
$ python manage.py sql appname
```

See if the datefield in question is a "reltime" field as I suspect. If this is the case, I'm at a loss about how to change it to a more compatable field without messing everything up.

Comment: I checked, its "born" timestamp with time zone NULL".

Comment: @bluejeansummer hey, i still couldn't find a way to get rid of this problem.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with PostgreSQL, as I usually use either SQLite or MySQL for django, so I don't think I can suggest anything you haven't already tried.

Comment: @bluejeansummer So, you mean this issue works fine on SQLite or MySQL?
If it is then its not a django problem rght?